# Controller's helper method on factory instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have helper method "current_cart" in application controller:

```
 helper_method :current_cart

def current_cart
    if !session[:cart_id].nil?
        Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    else
        Cart.new
    end
end
```

In line_item factory I try assign a value current cart to cart_id:

```
cart_id "#{current_cart}"
```

Error:

```
"ArgumentError: Trait not registered: current_cart"
```

What is the right way to use "current_cart" method in line_item factory?

Comment: Its not possible. Factories are not and should not be aware of the session. If you can try to describe the scenario you are trying to test instead we can give a better suggestion.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for answer. I try testing controller for cart and line_items. And simple acceptance test for cart page: cart is empty, cart have line_items, user see only his line_items in cart. Problem only in user session.

Comment: more precisely problem in cart_id value when line_item create:
`let!(:line_items) { create_list(:line_item, 5, :quantity_random, :product_auto, cart_id: ???) }` I need id from current cart

Comment: You could stub the `current_cart` method or do whatever steps are required to setup the current cart for the user.

Comment: if I use "current_cart" cart created automatically for all user (registered and anonymous). I can use current_user metod in cart controller, 
but it does not work for anonymous users. I have not other idea to implement this functionality

Comment: use all steps for add line_items in cart it's too complicated for such a simple task. Now it lacks only cart_id in line_item.